# Selenium getText() method does not get correct text with diacritics

Tags: java, intellij-idea, selenium-webdriver, gettext

I am trying to get text from a field that contains diacritics like: ă,ă-Ă-â-Â-î-Î-ş-Ş-ţ-Ţ
[image: web page source]

My method for get text looks like this:

```
    public  void invalidEmailValidation(){
    String expectedInner = LoginPage.invalidMailMessage(driver).getAttribute("innerText");
    String expectedText =  LoginPage.invalidMailMessage(driver).getText();
    System.out.print("EXPECTED1: " + expectedInner + "\n" +
                     "EXPECTED2: " + expectedText );
    Assert.assertEquals("Expcted Inner: Adresa de email nu este validă",
            expectedInner, "Adresa de email nu este validă");
    Assert.assertEquals("Expcted text: Adresa de email nu este validă",
            expectedText, "Adresa de email nu este validă");
```

The output from the method is here:
[image: console output]

I mention that my project have UTF-8 encoding
[image: project encoding: UTF-8]
Also UTF-8 encoding is added in pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

Other informations:
IDE: IntellijIdea 14.1.4 (comunity version)
OS: Windows 7 (english language as default)
I already checked the following questions from StackOverflow:
[Cannot verify text with diacritics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21116392/cannot-verify-text-which-contains-diacritics)
[Empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20888592/gettext-method-of-selenium-chrome-driver-sometimes-returns-an-empty-string)

Comment: In the middle of your screenshot where the expected and actual text is printed, there is a link that states <Click to see difference>. What does it display? I'm just wondering if there is some character in there like a non-breaking space or something that is different other than the letters.

Comment: @JeffC It says that strings are identical, and the string that is compared is "Adresa de mail nu este valid?"

Comment: It's failing because the strings are not the same. If you click to see the difference, it doesn't show anything? It may be that there are non-printable characters in there that are causing it to fail. You could do a character by character comparison of the two strings and log the ASCII codes of each. That should help you determine where the failure is.